# fixed orientation for some view controllers

Tags: ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

In my app i've both tabbar and navigationBar. rootview controller tabbar and tabbar has 4 navigation controller.

I want to make some viewcontrollers to be portrait only. It may be a common question but I've tried enough but I could not solve this.

How to make portrait orientation for some view Controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem and answering so that if someone face same problem they can get a help.

```
shouldAutorotate, supportedInterfaceOrientations, preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
```

The above methods don't get called of a viewcontroller if they are inside any tabbarcontroller of navigationcontroller. If these methods are declared inside tabbarcontroller or navigation controller then they will get called. In my case the viewcontrollers was inside navigationcontroller and the navigation controllers are inside a tabbarcontroller.

For solving this I make a class FixedOrientationTab, it is a subclass of UITabBarController, and a navigation class OrientationEnabledNavigation, it is a subclass of UINavigationController. Then I implemented `shouldAutorotate, supportedInterfaceOrientations, preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` methods inside FixedOrientationTab and OrientationEnabledNavigation.

**OrientationEnabledNavigation.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface OrientationEnabledNavigation : UINavigationController

@end
```

**OrientationEnabledNavigation.m**

```
#import "OrientationEnabledNavigation.h"

@interface OrientationEnabledNavigation ()

@end

@implementation OrientationEnabledNavigation

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return [self.topViewController shouldAutorotate];
//    return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return [self.topViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return [self.topViewController preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

**FixedOrientationTab.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FixedOrientationTab : UITabBarController

@end
```

**FixedOrientationTab.m**

```
#import "FixedOrientationTab.h"

@interface FixedOrientationTab ()

@end

@implementation FixedOrientationTab

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return [self.selectedViewController shouldAutorotate];
    //    return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return [self.selectedViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return [self.selectedViewController preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Then if you want to use navigation controller in your project then use OrientationEnabledNavigation and for tabbar FixedOrientationTab. After that if you implement `shouldAutorotate, supportedInterfaceOrientations, preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` these method inside your viewcontroller then they will get called.

Hope this helps.. :)