# How to rotate a single view from portrait to landscape in iOS 6 and above?

Tags: ios, iphone, screen-orientation

I am not able to rotate a single screen from portrait to landscape. So if i want to do this, then i have to revise the whole application into portrait and landscape mode?

Answer (score 0):

No you don't need to revise the whole application.

There are some delegate method By which you can do it. If your app has tabbar or navigationbar [see my question also answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21747851/fixed-orientation-for-some-view-controllers) by me. It will help.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method if you want to rotate screen in landscape mode

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation

 {

return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);

}
```

if you want to rotate in all the direction then return YES;

Answer (score 0):

I am also find the same problem.i have found that shouldAutorotate function not call every time so i change orientation programmatic

first import this

```
#import <objc/message.h>
```

then

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

     if(UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation)){
        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(setOrientation:)])
        {
            objc_msgSend([UIDevice currentDevice], @selector(setOrientation:), UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft );


        }
    }

}
```

hope this help you.